# How to get rid of https if included in the input

Tags: string, validation, go, user-input

My current code takes in arguments (the first being a URL) which is called `installationDNS`. Currently I expect the user to not input a URL with `https`, but if they do include `https` in the URL how do I get rid of it?

For example if they enter `https://randomDNS.com`, I just want the `randomDNS.com` part.

```
if len(args) == 0 {
    return nil, true, errors.New("must provide an installation DNS")
}
installationDNS := standardizeName(args[0])
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question displays lacking of any attempt at solving the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You probably also want to trim `http://`, and remove any path after that, thus only get the domain from the url.

The [`net/url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) package comes in handy. You can do the following:

```
const link = "https://randomdns.com"
u, err := url.Parse(link)
if err != nil {
    return nil, true, fmt.Errorf("error parsing url: %w", err)
}
fmt.Println("domain:", u.Hostname())
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rWLHwhQ_qCB)

This will always extract only the hostname part of the URL, and thus is the safest in front of user input.